# How to determine windows size of moving average filter

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, moving-average

I've recorded acceleration signal data using an accelerometer attached to vehicle , and I want to calculate the displacement of signal data using double integration or any other methods. I read many studies that perform moving average filter to acceleration data to reduce the amount of error caused by the suspension system of the vehicle.

How I can determine the ideal windows size of moving average filter for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'd look at the spectrum of your noise, and deduct an appropriate filter frequency response from that. When doing so you'll realize that the moving average is not a good filter (having sinc-shaped frequency response), and that you should be using a better filter design, aligned to what your signal actually needs.

So, you'd do three things:

1. you come up with a physical model of how fast the acceleration changes
2. you verify that with a look at the spectrum of your recorded signal, and look for where the noise in your recording is
3. you design a filter that has a passband where your expected signal is, and especially strong stopband suppression where only noise happens (hint: many accelerometers are swinging micromachined things, and there might be significant noise from that at subharmonics of the swing frequency)

Also, this is **the** classical example for which Kalman filters (or nonlinear variants of it, depending on how you plan to model your state) are used, instead of plain double integration.